# Determine holiday given the month and day

Tags: python

I need to write a function that returns the holiday, given the month and day numerically (7 4 is July 4th).

The holidays to return are:

```
1 1 "New Year's Day"
2 14 "Valentine's Day"
4 1 "April Fool's Day"
4 22 "Earth Day"
5 1 "May Day"
6 14 "Flag Day"
7 4 "Independence Day"
7 14 "Bastille Day"
10 31 "Halloween"
12 25 "Christmas"
```

If the day is not a holiday, you should return "Not a holiday".

This is what I've tried and it won't work as expected. If I input 4 1 my code says New Year's day.

```
def holiday(month,day):
    if month and day in (1, 1):
        return "New Year's Day"
    if month and day in (2, 14):
        return "Valentine's Day"
    if month and day in (4, 1):
        return "April Fool's Day"
    if month and day in (4,22):
        return "Earth Day"
    if month and day in (5, 1):
        return "May Day"
    if month and day in (6, 14):
        return "Flag Day"
    if month and day in (7, 4):
        return "Independence Day"
    if month and day in (7, 14):
        return "Bastille Day"
    if month and day in (10 ,31):
        return "Halloween"
    if month and day in (12, 25):
        return "Christmas"
```

Comment: why dont you try if month=1 and day =1 return "New Year's Day"?

Comment: @Kush, you mean: try `if month==1 and day==1; return "New Year's Day"`

Comment: it worked! thank you!

Comment: Or use a dict: `holidays = {(1, 1): "New Year's Day", (2, 14): "Valentine's Day"}` then you can do `print(holidays.get((month, day), "Not a holiday"))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest solution that comes to mind is accessing values via dict, so you don't have to write a bunch of `if` statements.. and if the holiday doesn't exists, just **catch the exception** and write your own message.

For example:

```
def holiday():
     return {
        1: {
            1: "New Year"
        },
        2: {
            14: "Valentines Day"
        }
    }

try:
    print(holiday()[2][14])
except KeyError:
    print("No holiday :(")
```

Keep in mind, you don't need a function for this, just a simple dict would be fine, but you said *I need to write a function* so there you go :)